# Starting Xorg using systemd

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, x11, login

As described in [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/556113/how-to-start-dhcpcd-in-background-on-boot), I use my .bash_profile to start Xorg on login. I am using a fresh install of Arch Linux.

The [Arch Wiki provides instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User#Xorg_as_a_systemd_user_service) for doing this using systemd instead, but notes that there are a few bugs (such as not being able to start Xorg unprivileged). However, these instructions are roughly 5 years old, and they suggest various fixes were being considered by systemd developers at the time of writing. Therefore, I am curious about the current state of Xorg and systemd.

Is it currently possible to start Xorg in unprivileged mode as a user service with systemd?